# Merging data between 2 separate Oracle databases

Tags: database, oracle

I've got two separate, unconnected and unconnectable Oracle databases. I need to get information from one to the other as quickly and painlessly as possible.

Typically what I've done up until now when in this situation is create a staging area for the data that needs to be imported (essentially a temporary table just for storing the data until I'm done merging). I copy *all* of the data that *might* be needed from the source to that staging area. Then I merge the data as I would if the two tables were connected, meaning of course that I can filter out whatever data I don't need at that time.

Here's the problem in my current case. The source table is *extremely* large and entirely *un-indexed* (something over which I have no control, ugh). That means it takes **forever** to get the necessary data if I don't filter it in some way. In addition the destination table really only needs a relatively small subset of the data to do what it needs to do, maybe ten thousand or so distinct rows at a time. In this case I don't want to copy *all* of the data that *might* be needed. I just want to copy over the *exact* data that will be needed, or as close to that as possible.

**tl:dr version**

**Exactly how do I limit my select on the source table based on what I need in the destination table if they can't communicate with each other?**

For example, I might select ID's for the data that is needed in the destination and build the query for the source table based on that. However, that might result in a query with many thousands of OR clauses in it:

```
SELECT x, y FROM z WHERE (ID = 1 OR ID = 2 ... OR ID = 10000 OR ID = 10001...)
```

Or something like that. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Even if the two databases can't talk to each other, can you position a client so it can communicate with both databases simultaneously?

Comment: How do you know what you need, is it just new rows since a certain date, or something more subtle?

Comment: It's the set of distinct ID's of a foreign key added since a certain date. So the initial select would be something like "SELECT DISTINCT FOREIGN_KEY_ID FROM TABLEX WHERE DATE_ADDED > '2012-01-01';"

Answer (score 3):

Can you temporarily create a dblink between two oracle databases? That would enable you to build a SQL statement that references tables from the two different databases.

Comment: I'm not an actual DBA for either of them, and I'm pretty much limited to SELECT privileges on the source and SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE privileges on the destination. Unless a dblink is something that can be done independently of the DBAs then that is not an option. If it is independent, then that sounds like what I need to do.

Comment: It will make things much easier if you can get one created. Try talking to the DBAs and see if they'll go for it.

Comment: Apparently there are things that we are not allowed to access on the source which a dblink would necessarily expose. I'm not sure if that's a failing of the technology, or a failing of the personnel, but that's their final answer.

Comment: That's a failing of your personnel, but oh well. Just FYI, they could have set things up so you could only see what they wanted you to see.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a firewall or something preventing the DB instances from communicating?
If so, you could always extract to a tab delimited data set from the source, then load into the target from that.  The select could look something like

```
SELECT x, y FROM z WHERE ID IN (1, 2, ..., 10000, 10001, ...)
```

If too many in-list items you can put your in-list items in a temporary table and join to that.  OR follow Tom Kyte's example: 
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425
http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/06/varying-in-lists.html

The easiest thing to do is link to source instance from target instance, then say something like:

```
insert into staging (SELECT x, y FROM z@linkname WHERE ID IN (1, 2, ..., 10000, 10001, ...))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an option would be to load the set of ids into the source.  This sounds potentially annoying to have to do routinely.  Can you put an apex application on the source?

These days there are standard application features which allow you to  set up an application to declaratively load of csv containing the IDs (or you coudl kuse theload data option from the apex interface), and then of course apex can report on the required rows and you can download them as csv...I don't think 10 000 rows should give you any problem with this technique)

Apex should be able to make this pretty fast and simple!

Answer (score 0):

You could use dbms_output to get data into the source database into an array. 
And then use the array in your select clause. This is how it would work in sqlplus

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR

declare t DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY;
    numlines integer;
    c sys_refcursor;
begin
  dbms_output.enable;
  dbms_output.put_line(100);
  dbms_output.put_line(116);
  -- add more object ids ....
  dbms_output.get_lines(t,numlines);
  open :cur for select object_id,object_name 
   from all_objects o where o.object_id in 
   (select * from table(t));
end;
/

print cur
```

gives me:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
       100 ORA$BASE
       116 DUAL
```

Spool the query result into a file and load it into your target db.